# show first image in css definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have this inline css/ haml

```
:css        
      .testimonials{
        background: url('/assets/#{@house.slug}.jpg');
        padding: 80px 0;
         background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;/* IE FIX */
      }
```

This shows a image from the assets folder from the related house in a parallax scrolling website.

I use carrierwave to manage the images for all houses, and I now want to show the first image in the css background definition so I don't have to upload a image to the assets folder anymore.

```
- @house.attachments.each.first do |a|
    = image_tag(a.file.url(:thumb))
```

How can I place this loop in the inline css definition?

thanks..remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using style option

```
image_tag a.file.url(:thumb), :style => "background: url(a.file.url(:thumb))"
```

even no need to image_tag just any div add style option for background image